# $1+(\frac{x}{y}-\sin y)y' = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$1+(\frac{x}{y}-\sin y)y'  = 0$$

I'm trying to transform this equation into an exact one. I tried multiplying by $\phi(x)$ (a function depending only on $x$ in order to find the integrating factor) but the EDO involving the integrating factor was not ordinary. I then tried with $\phi(y)$ and I almost got it:

$$\phi(y) + \phi(y)(\frac{x}{y}-\sin y)y' = 0$$

$$M = \phi(y) \implies M_y = \phi_y(y)$$

$$N = \phi(y)(\frac{x}{y}-\sin y) \implies N_y = \phi(y)\frac{1}{y}+0$$

Since we must have $M_y = N_x$:

oooops, I just discovered my error, I was doing $M_y+N_x$ but it's $M_y = N_x$, so we get:

$$\phi_y(y) = \phi(y)\frac{1}{y}\implies$$

$$\phi(y) = y$$

then the equation is exact.

I'll let the question here since I written, this might help someone in the year 2047 that's reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve equation respect to the $x$ variable so as 
$$ 1+(\frac { x }{ y } -\sin  y)y'=0\\ 1+(\frac { x }{ y } -\sin  y)\frac { dy }{ dx } =0\\ \frac { dx }{ dy } +\frac { x }{ y } -\sin { y } =0\\ y{ x }^{ \prime  }+x=y\sin { y } \\ d\left( xy \right) =y\sin { y } \\ xy=\int { y\sin { y } dy } =-\int { yd\cos { y } =-y\cos { y } +\sin { y } +C } $$
so

> $$
> xy=-y\cos { y } +\sin { y } +C
> $$

Comment: This assumes that $x$ is expressible in terms of $y$, or in other words that the solution is invertible (at least locally) and this has to be justified (and the point(s) near which the function is invertible should be specified as well)

Comment: @user00000 has a legitimate point. The problem itself is an easy ODE. The justification is not hard either. So this solution as it stands, without the justification, is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply rewrite he equation in a form where $x = x(y)$ and then you see that 
$$\frac{dx}{dy} + \left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \,x = \sin{y},$$ which is linear...

Comment: No, you can't simply do that because you will be assuming that the function is a bijection (at least locally). So, at least some further justification is needed

Comment: Yes, actually I can simply do that. Look, I have even done it in my post!

Comment: Okay, but the gods of math are going to punish you soon.

Comment: Just I have commented regarding haqnatural's answer, @user00000 makes a more-than-legitimate point. It does not take much to justify the method. This answer as it stands is incomplete as a solution. Of course, you can claim it is merely a hint. It is an easy problem, anyway.